# How to handle data manipulation when using importrange() in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on speeding up a workbook in Google sheets that is using importrange(). The purpose of the entire workbook is to import data from a mastersheet and then allow us to manipulate it the way we want to outside of the mastersheet.

The problem: because importrange() doesn't allow you to directly manipulate cells we have Sheet1 acting as the import sheet; it doesn't get touched. Sheet2 is where we do the manipulating but, it was literally just taken as a copy of Sheet1, so it is also using importrange(). This bogs down the entire workbook and makes manipulations very slow.

I am thinking of using !Sheet1A1... and copying that to all the cells in the manipulation sheet, but my concern is that this will still bog down the workbook. There is potential that the import data could grow as large as 10k+ rows, and I'm only at about half that currently and running into this problem. Outside of that, I'm not sure what else there is to try.

Answer (score 0):

The `QUERY` function can help here and there are some great resources online.

=importrange(spreadsheet_url, range_string)

a typical example is:

`=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","Sheet1!A:Z")`

You can wrap a `QUERY` function around this to manipulate your data.

`QUERY` is like a version of SQL and very powerful. It's in the format:

`=QUERY({},"",1)`

Your data range `importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","Sheet1!A:Z")` would go within `{}`.

Then within the `""` part of the query, you could write your parameters for manipulating the data.

Example:

`select Col1,Col4,Col5 where Col1 is not null and Col6 contains 'hello' order by Col1,Col7 desc label Col1 'new name 1',Col4 'new name 4'`

The `select` bit allows you to specify specific columns from your importrange. If you want the all, then you could use `select *`.

The `where` item is where you build up your criteria using various `or` or `and` parameters.

`is not null` is another way of saying you want rows that have data.

`contains` is useful. You can also have `matches`, `starts with`, `ends with` and `like`. `like` can use wildcards `%`, so `where Col1 like '%the%'` would find 'hello there'.

`order by` is ascending unless you add `desc`, ie. `order by Col1,Col2,Col4,Col5 desc,Col3`.

`label` allows you to rename the columns, so let's say input column 1 is called 'Name1' and input column 2 is 'Name2' and you want them to be 'First name' and 'Surname, you would use `label Col1 'First name', Col2 'Surname'`.

If you like `QUERY` there are other powerful clauses, and they run in this order within the `QUERY(range,"clauses",0)`:

`select`

`where`

`group by`

`pivot`

`order by`

`limit`

`offset`

`label`

`format`

`options`

One small point which you may come across, when you use importrange to get your data you need to reference the columns as `Col1,Col2,Col3` within the `QUERY`.

If, however, your range is already in the same sheet (same or different tab), then you would reference column letters instead, eg. `select A,B,C where A is not null order by A desc`.

To make it more consistent and use the `Col1,Col2,Col3` notation, you would put your internal range in an array `{}`.

`QUERY(Sheet1!B:F,"select B,C,D where F is not null order by B,C",0)`

would become:

`QUERY({Sheet1!B:F},"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col5 is not null order by Col1,Col2",0)`

`{Sheet1!B:F}` is smart because you can add columns in front of this range without needing to change your clause. So adding one column in front of Sheet1, would result in:

`QUERY({Sheet1!C:G},"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col5 is not null order by Col1,Col2",0)`

The other method would need you to alter your clause from:

`QUERY(Sheet1!B:F,"select B,C,D where F is not null order by B,C",0)`

to:

`QUERY(Sheet1!C:G,"select C,D,E where G is not null order by C,D",0)`

It's a lot to take in, but definitely worth persuing!